# Numpy percentages along axis in 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix of counts,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[ 1,2,3],[1,4,6],[2,3,7]])
```

And I need the percentages of the total along axis = 1:

```
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        x[i,j] = x[i,j] / np.sum(x[i,:])
```

In numpy broadcast form.

Currently, I have:

```
x_sums = np.sum(x,axis=1)
for j in range(x.shape[1]):
     x[:,j] = x[:,j] / x_sums[:]
```

Which puts most of the complexity in numpy code...but a numpy one liner would be best.

Also,

```
def percentages(a):
    return a / np.sum(a)

x_percentages = np.apply_along_axis(percentages,1,x)
```

But that still involves python.

---

```
 np.linalg.norm
```

Is very close, in terms of what is going on, but they only have the 8 hardcoded norms, which does not include percentage of total.

Then there is `np.percentile`, which is again close...but it is computing the sorted percentile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
x /= x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Altough `x` should have a floating point dtype for this to work correctly.

Better may be:

```
x = np.true_divide(x, x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

Comment: Nice!  I think that will do it.   Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Could this be what you are after:

```
print (x.T/np.sum(x, axis=1)).T
```